# Has anyone created a MonoTouch binding for the Nuance Dragon Mobile Speech SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, speech-recognition

I have the Dragon Mobile SDK running nicely on Windows Phone 7 and I would like to get the equivalent functionality working for iOS.  Since the SDK wraps the microphone, it's not really possible to use the .NET assemblies in my MonoTouch project (even if I did have the source).  It appears that the best way to do this is to create a binding library (as Miguel describes [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types)).

It sure seems like a lot of work though, and I would love to reuse as opposed to reinventing the wheel if someone's done it already...

Comment: is Dragon/Nuance suitable for general dictation on a mobile device?  Yours is the only code I've come across in an hour of searching so I'm wondering whether support has improved for Xamarin devs and how useful the technology is these days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some more details for how I got this to work.

1. I downloaded the [binding sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/BindingSample).  You may be tempted to skip this step, but you really have to start with this project if you want to get this to work.
2. I created an objective-c library with Xcode (which I called SpeechKitLibrary) that has a dual purpose - one is to define the SpeechKitApplicationKey (which is an extern dependency that SpeechKit needs):

   ```
   const unsigned char SpeechKitApplicationKey[] = {...};
   ```

   and the other is to define a class which utilizes the SpeechKit framework, and links with it.  (in Xcode, add the SpeechKit framework in the frameworks section of the project).

   The .m file I wrote looks something like this... (you can figure out the .h file - super simple).  I'm not 100% sure you need all of this, but I wanted to make sure the static archive library that came out of this step would import the  right symbols.  You may be able to avoid this somehow, but in my experiments I found that I needed to do something like this...

   ```
   // the SpeechKitWrapper isn't actually used - rather, it is a way to exercise all the API's that 
   // the binding library needs from the SpeechKit framework, so that those can be linked into the generated .a file.

   @implementation SpeechKitWrapper
   @synthesize status;

   - (id)initWithDelegate:(id <SKRecognizerDelegate>)delegate
   {
       self = [super init];
       if (self) {
           del = delegate;
           [self setStatus:@"initializing"];
           SpeechKit setupWithID:@"NMDPTRIAL_ogazitt20120220010133"
                         host:@"sandbox.nmdp.nuancemobility.net"
                         port:443
                       useSSL:NO
                     delegate:nil];

       NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"initialized.  sessionid = %@", [SpeechKit sessionID]];
       [self setStatus:text];        

       SKEarcon* earconStart   = [SKEarcon earconWithName:@"beep.wav"];
       [SpeechKit setEarcon:earconStart forType:SKStartRecordingEarconType];

       voiceSearch = [[SKRecognizer alloc] initWithType:SKDictationRecognizerType
                                              detection:SKLongEndOfSpeechDetection
                                               language:@"en_US" 
                                               delegate:delegate];

       text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"recognizer connecting.  sessionid = %@", [SpeechKit sessionID]];
       [self setStatus:text];  
       }

       return self;
   }

   @end
   ```
3. I then compiled/linked this static archive for the three different architectures - i386, arm6, and arm7.  The Makefile in the BindingSample is the template for how to do this.  But the net is that you get three libraries - libSpeechKitLibrary-{i386,arm6,arm7}.a.  The makefile then creates a universal library (libSpeechKitLibraryUniversal.a) using the OSX lipo(1) tool.
4. Only now are you ready to create a binding library.  You can reuse the AssemblyInfo.cs in the binding sample (which will show how to create an import on the universal library for all architectures - and will drive some compile flags)...

   ```
   [assembly: LinkWith ("libSpeechKitLibraryUniversal.a", LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.ArmV6 | LinkTarget.ArmV7, ForceLoad = true)]
   ```
5. You compile the ApiDefinition.cs file with btouch as per the Makefile (I think I needed to repeat some of the info in StructsAndEnums.cs to make it work).  Note - the only functionality I didn't get to work is the "SetEarcon" stuff - since this is an archive library and not a framework, I can't bundle a wav as a resource file... and I couldn't figure out how to get the SetEarcon method to accept a resource out of my app bundle.

   ```
   using System;
   using MonoTouch.Foundation;

   namespace Nuance.SpeechKit
   {
   // SKEarcon.h
   public enum SKEarconType
   {
       SKStartRecordingEarconType = 1,
       SKStopRecordingEarconType = 2,
       SKCancelRecordingEarconType = 3,
   };

   // SKRecognizer.h
   public enum SKEndOfSpeechDetection 
   {
       SKNoEndOfSpeechDetection = 1,
       SKShortEndOfSpeechDetection = 2,
       SKLongEndOfSpeechDetection = 3,
   };

   public static class SKRecognizerType
   {
       public static string SKDictationRecognizerType = "dictation";
       public static string SKWebSearchRecognizerType = "websearch";
   };

   // SpeechKitErrors.h
   public enum SpeechKitErrors
   {
       SKServerConnectionError = 1,
       SKServerRetryError = 2,
       SKRecognizerError = 3,
       SKVocalizerError = 4,
       SKCancelledError = 5,
   };

   // SKEarcon.h
   [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
   interface SKEarcon 
   {
       [Export("initWithContentsOfFile:")]
       IntPtr Constructor(string path);

       [Static, Export("earconWithName:")]
       SKEarcon FromName(string name);
   }   

   // SKRecognition.h
   [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
   interface SKRecognition
   {
       [Export("results")]
       string[] Results { get; }

       [Export("scores")]
       NSNumber[] Scores { get; }

       [Export("suggestion")]
       string Suggestion { get; }

       [Export("firstResult")]
       string FirstResult();
   }

   // SKRecognizer.h
   [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
   interface SKRecognizer
   {
       [Export("audioLevel")]
       float AudioLevel { get; }

       [Export ("initWithType:detection:language:delegate:")]
       IntPtr Constructor (string type, SKEndOfSpeechDetection detection, string language, SKRecognizerDelegate del);

       [Export("stopRecording")]
       void StopRecording();

       [Export("cancel")]
       void Cancel();

       /*
       [Field ("SKSearchRecognizerType", "__Internal")]
       NSString SKSearchRecognizerType { get; }

       [Field ("SKDictationRecognizerType", "__Internal")]
       NSString SKDictationRecognizerType { get; }
       */
   }

   [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
   [Model]
   interface SKRecognizerDelegate
   {
       [Export("recognizerDidBeginRecording:")]
       void OnRecordingBegin (SKRecognizer recognizer);

       [Export("recognizerDidFinishRecording:")]
       void OnRecordingDone (SKRecognizer recognizer);

       [Export("recognizer:didFinishWithResults:")]
       [Abstract]
       void OnResults (SKRecognizer recognizer, SKRecognition results);

       [Export("recognizer:didFinishWithError:suggestion:")]
       [Abstract]
       void OnError (SKRecognizer recognizer, NSError error, string suggestion);
   }   

   // speechkit.h
   [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
   interface SpeechKit
   {
       [Static, Export("setupWithID:host:port:useSSL:delegate:")]
       void Initialize(string id, string host, int port, bool useSSL, [NullAllowed] SpeechKitDelegate del);

       [Static, Export("destroy")]
       void Destroy();

       [Static, Export("sessionID")]
       string GetSessionID();

       [Static, Export("setEarcon:forType:")]
       void SetEarcon(SKEarcon earcon, SKEarconType type);     
   }

   [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
   [Model]
   interface SpeechKitDelegate
   {
       [Export("destroyed")]
       void Destroyed();   
   }   

   [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
   interface SpeechKitWrapper
   {
       [Export("initWithDelegate:")]
       IntPtr Constructor(SKRecognizerDelegate del);

       [Export("status")]
       string Status { get; set; }
   }
   }
   ```
6. You now have an assembly that can be referenced by your monotouch application project.  The important thing now is to remember to link with all the frameworks that are dependencies  (not only SpeeckKit, but also SK's dependencies) - you do this by passing mtouch some additional arguments:

   ```
   -gcc_flags "-F<insert_framework_path_here> -framework SpeechKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox"
   ```

That's all, folks!  Hope this was helpful...

If anyone (kos or otherwise) gets the SetEarcon method to work, please post a solution :-)

Comment: Omri, much appreciated. Just to clarify in step 2 - the library contains a SpeechKitWrapper.m and SpeechKitWrapper.h, but where do you define the SpeechKitApplicationKey? In SpeechKitWrapper.m or a separate file? Also, is `status` the same as `setStatus`? Thanks....

Comment: doesn't matter - i put it in SpeechKitWrapper.m (above the @implementation).  I defined SpeechKitWrapper.h like this...

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SpeechKit/SpeechKit.h>

\@interface SpeechKitWrapper : NSObject //<SKRecognizerDelegate>
{
    NSString *status;
    SKRecognizer *voiceSearch;
    NSObject *del;
}

\@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *status;

\@end

Comment: thanks Omri, managed to generate the dll. My (hopefully) last question is regarding the touch argument. I keep getting the "Native linking failed. Please review user flags provided to gcc". My argument is as follows `-gcc_flags "-F/Users/kos/Projects/MySolution/MyProject/Frameworks -framework SpeechKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox"` where in Frameworks folder I copied the `SpeechKit.framework` and `libSpeechKitLibraryUniversal.a`. I tried various other paths. Am I missing something? Again, really thankful for your help...

Comment: you don't need to move the libSpeechKitLibraryUniversal.a - the "linkwith" attribute in assemblyinfo.cs should cause the .a to be embedded in the dll.  besides -F only works for frameworks not for static libs (see ld(1)).  Stepping back, there are a bunch of steps that I list above.  Trust me, they will all make alot more sense if you download the BindingSample and take the time to understand what the makefile is doing.  Get that thing working first (including deploying it on the simulator).  Then start substituting your code into that sample.  That will make it easier... good luck!!

Comment: Thanks again. I actually downloaded and got the BindingSample to work - you are right, definitely worth doing it before attempting the rest. However, The BindingSample hasn't got any mtouch arguments that will help me with the arguments needed for my project. Just wondering what needs to go in the `-F<insert_framework_path_here>` argument - i.e. is it the original Xcode `SpeechKit.framework`, and if so, do I need to copy it into my project path and link it from there?

Comment: Yes: -F <SpeechKit.framework path> -f SpeechKit  ...  the path itself doesn't matter (i.e. you don't have to copy the framework anywhere).  Make sure you have a SpeechKit file and Headers and Resources directories inside that SpeechKit.framework directory that you're pointing to.  Also, you want to make sure you're passing these arguments to mtouch when you're compiling/linking the actual app, not the Binding Library that you created.

Answer (score 2):

Nuance's SDK Agreement is not permissive enough for anyone to even publish bindings for their iOS SDK for use with MonoTouch. But the library itself *should* work just fine.

That being said, the SDK has only a handful of types to map and would be fairly trivial to RE-do the work anyone else might have already done. You can check out how to bind assemblies using the reference guide here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types

There's also a BindingSample project that helps users better understand how to bind native components using btouch:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/BindingSample

Comment: I have been doing exactly that (coding up the binding library as described in the link you mentioned - which is the same one I quoted in my original question).  I still haven't gotten it to work though (still struggling with the linking it in, since it's a framework as opposed to a libX.a).  Is there a binding sample you know of that binds a framework (obviously MonoTouch binds every CocoaTouch framework - UIKit, etc - so it must be possible).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again Anuj for your answer.  I thought I'd leave a tip or two about how to do this.  The binding library wasn't difficult to build (still tweaking it but it's not a difficult task).

The more obscure part was figuring out how to get the SpeechKit framework linked.  The samples only show how to link a .a or .dylib.  After spending a little time with the ld(1) man page on OSX, it looks like the correct ld (and therefore gcc) arguments for linking with a framework are the following:

```
-gcc_flags "-F<insert_framework_path_here> -framework SpeechKit"
```

You put this in a textbox in the project properties - under Build :: iPhone Build :: Additional mtouch arguments

Note that -L doesn't work because this isn't a library; also note that -force_load and -ObjC referenced [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types) don't appear necessary because, again, this is a framework and not a library.

Comment: There is usually a statically compiled library inside a given *.framework folder. Also try the new LinkWith attribute :-)

Comment: Update: I finally got this to work - Anuj's binding sample was definitely the way to go.  I could never get the Binding Library project template to work for me - instead I did what most other people seem to be doing - using btouch explicitly and adopting Anuj's approach of creating a universal static library that contains the arm6, arm7 and i386 static libs.  The other very important thing is not to forget to use the -F<path> -framework <framework> mtouch arguments on the APPLICATION project.

Comment: any chance of sharing the library over github?  I would really appreciate to reuse if this is possible.

Comment: kos - see anuj's comment above - he's right - nuance won't permit it.  it took me a couple of days (seems like it was harder than it should be) but it's definitely doable.

Comment: Omri - am struggling to get this to work. Any chance of showing how you defined the ApiDefinition.cs wrapper? I am trying to get this to work for the SpeechKit, SKRecognizer and SKRecognition classes.

Comment: kos - I just posted another answer which has more detailed instructions (hopefully without violating Nuance's t&c ;-)).  Best of luck!