# Monotouch binding issue after updating to xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios

I had previously managed to get a test program in MonoTouch working with the Nuance SpeechKit  by following the steps detailed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372880/has-anyone-created-a-monotouch-binding-for-the-nuance-dragon-mobile-speech-sdk-f).

I have since updated everything to the latest and greatest (IOS 6.0, xcode 4.5 etc.).

The first time I followed all of the same steps as before I had issues regarding ARMv6 support. I believe I correctly changed the architecture settings of the project to remove the ARMv6 references. I was able to follow the binding steps (from post above) and everything seems to build ok.

The problem I'm seeing is in the MonoTouch project.  After replacing the referenced DLL with the newly created one, I'm getting missing reference errors.

It seems as though the newly created DLL is not exposing the SpeechKit framework. (The older original DLL showed the SpeechKit framework just fine.)

(I am definitely a beginner so forgive me if I mutilate the following...)

The original steps I followed to create this binding (linked to above) had me create a wrapper file in the xcode project.  The code in this wrapper references the SpeechKit framework.  There is a comment in the example that indicates this code is not actually used but is needed for the linking. (Comments below)

```
// the SpeechKitWrapper isn't actually used - rather, it is a way to exercise all the API's that 
// the binding library needs from the SpeechKit framework, so that those can be linked into the generated .a file.
```

To me the problem seems to be that the steps I'm following no longer does this.  I don't know if there is a project setting or something that has changed that causing this.  Or maybe something completely unrelated.

Does anyone have any insight into what might be going wrong for me?