# Getting text from speech on Xamarin.iOS to start a method

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, speech-recognition

I'm developing an application for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS and therefore I would need a possibility to start a recorder by just giving a command by speech.
I've found some sample here https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/App/VoiceRecognition.cs for Android ...

My question is how to do that in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a 3rd party library for that.
For example:
http://wiki.ios.xamarin.com/index.php?title=HowTo/Interop/Interopping_with_Open_Source_Text-to-Speech_%28TTS%29_C_libraries__for_iPhone.&galleryOffset=showall

or Nuance's Dragon Voice to Text API:
[Has anyone created a MonoTouch binding for the Nuance Dragon Mobile Speech SDK for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372880/has-anyone-created-a-monotouch-binding-for-the-nuance-dragon-mobile-speech-sdk-f)

Comment: Thanks, I've found this binding for iOS here: https://github.com/oganix/MonoTouch-OpenEars
It's free and for offline use.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @nhaberl - I hope someone else would find this useful as well :).