# Implementing Xamarin iOS Speech to Text

Tags: ios, mobile, xamarin, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to figure out a way to do speech recognition/speech to text on Xamarin iOS. I have been doing a lot of research and so far it seems like this is a feature only available for Android Xamarin Development.

Does anyone have an idea of how to appraoch this? Any links to resources or projects that have implemented this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can try open ears or dragon speech. There is no built in speech recognition for Xamarin.iOS that I am aware of.

https://github.com/oganix/MonoTouch-OpenEars

[Has anyone created a MonoTouch binding for the Nuance Dragon Mobile Speech SDK for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372880/has-anyone-created-a-monotouch-binding-for-the-nuance-dragon-mobile-speech-sdk-f)

### Update

Since iOS 10 you can now access the speech recognition apis documented below

https://blog.xamarin.com/speech-recognition-in-ios-10/?utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=blog&utm_source=linkedin&utm_content=ios10-speech-recognition

Android has for a long time had their APIs available for speech documented below

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/speech/